# How to use R libraries in Azure Databricks without depending on CRAN server connectivity?

Tags: r, databricks, azure-databricks

We are using a few R libraries in Azure Databricks which do not come preinstalled. To install these libraries during Job Runs on Job Clusters, we use an init script to install them.

```sh
sudo R --vanilla -e 'install.packages("package_name", 
   repos="https://mran.microsoft.com/snapsot/YYYY-MM-DD")'
```

During one of our production runs, the Microsoft Server was down (could the timing be any worse?) and the job failed.

As a workaround, we now install libraries in `/dbfs/folder_x` and when we want to use them, we include the following block in our R code:

```r
.libpaths('/dbfs/folder_x')
library("libraryName")
```

This does work for us, but what is the ideal solution to this? Since, if we want to update a library to another version, remove a library or add one, we have to go through the following steps everytime and there is a chance of forgetting this during code promotions:

```r
install.packages("xyz")
system("cp -R /databricks/spark/R/lib/xyz /dbfs/folder_x/xyz")
```

It is a very simple and workable solution, but not ideal.

Comment: What's wrong with `install.packages("xyz", lib = "/dbfs/folder_x")`? Alternatively, why not just set `R_LIBS` environment variable when starting R? See `?libPaths`.

Comment: The issue is with server connection or server being down when (for example) the Microsoft CRAN goes down again! install.packages still does depend on this connection, or do you mean it as an alternative way to save it to dbfs as I am doing anyway?

Comment: As an alternative way to save it. You are then using the same one-line command. I'm not sure what else could be shorter than this. Essentially, you are moving your library to a non-standard location. That's not unusual, and there are plenty of tools to do this. If you want a more advanced solution for managing libraries, maybe renv would help.